# AngularJS Promise Returns Empty Array

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have this code in a factory:

```
  getAyahsByJuz: function (juzIndex) {
        var response = [];
        var promises = [];

        var self = this;
        var deferred = $q.defer();
        $timeout(function () {
            $http.get('data/quran.json').success(function (data) {
                var ayahs = Quran.ayah.listFromJuz(juzIndex);
                angular.forEach(ayahs, function (value, key) {
                    var promise = self.getVerse(value.surah, value.ayah).then(function (res) {
                        var verse = {
                            surah: value.surah,
                            ayah: value.ayah,
                            text: res
                        };
                        response.push(verse);
                    }, function (err) {
                        console.log(err);
                    });
                    promises.push(promise);
                });
            });
        }, 30);

        $q.all(promises).then(function() {
            deferred.resolve(response);
        });

        return deferred.promise;
    },
```

Please note that everything is working fine the `verse` object is returning properly. However, when I use this in a controller using `.then(res)`. `res` returns `[]` instead of the array filled with the verse objects.

Can anyone point out why? Thanks!

Comment: Did you try to put `$q.all(promises)` inside `$timeout` function?

Comment: @cespon yup, same result -> `[]`

Answer (score 3):

The short answer is because your `$q.all` runs before `$timeout` & before the `$http` embedded in `$timeout`. Let's boil your original code down to its relevant components:

```
getAyahsByJuz: function (juzIndex) {
    var response = [];
    var promises = [];
    var deferred = $q.defer();
    // ...irrelevant stuff that will happen after a $timeout
    // this happens IMMEDIATELY (before $timeout):
    $q.all(promises).then(function() { // wait for empty promise array
        deferred.resolve(response); // resolve with empty response array
    }); // side note: this is a broken chain! deferred.promise can't reject

    return deferred.promise; // send promise for empty array
}
```

See the problem? If for some odd reason you need to keep that `$timeout`, here's the fix with substantial promise refactoring & removing the [awful jquery-inspired non-promisy `success` syntax](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/10508)):

```
getAyahsByJuz: function (juzIndex) {
    var self = this;
    // $timeout itself returns a promise which we can post-process using its callback return value
    return $timeout(function () {
        // returning the $http promise modifies the $timeout promise
        return $http.get('data/quran.json').then(function (response) { // you never used this response!

            var versePromises = [];

            var ayahs = Quran.ayah.listFromJuz(juzIndex);
            angular.forEach(ayahs, function (value, key) {
                // we'll push all versePromises into an array…
                var versePromise = self.getVerse(value.surah, value.ayah).then(function (res) {
                    // the return value of this `then` modifies `versePromise`
                    return {
                        surah: value.surah,
                        ayah: value.ayah,
                        text: res
                    };
                });
                versePromises.push(versePromise);
            });

            return $q.all(versePromises); // modifies $http promise — this is our ultimate promised value
            // if a versePromise fails, $q.all will fail; add a `catch` when using getAyahsByJuz!
        });
    }, 30);

}
```

However, there is still a huge issue here… why aren't you using the server response of your `$http` call anywhere? What is the point of that first call?

Also I find that `$timeout` to be extremely suspicious. If you need it then it's likely there's something bad going on elsewhere in the code.